# How to delete the default label in a Live Chart row chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, livecharts

I'm working on a Windows Forms application that uses the [Live Charts](https://lvcharts.net/) Add-in, and I need to get the default descriptor gone from an otherwise pretty simple bar chart. Sadly the site doesn't do a very good job of explaining itself, and the support chat is deader than Windows XP's update servers.

[image: This]

This  is the thing I need gone.

```
cartesianChart1.Series = new SeriesCollection { };
int counter = 0;
foreach (string number in daten)
{
    cartesianChart1.Series.Add(new RowSeries { Title = titel[counter], Values = new ChartValues<int> { Convert.ToInt16(number) }, DataLabels = true });
    counter++;
}
//cartesianChart1.AxisY.Remove();
```

Comment: Show us your current code

Comment: @PeMaCN There you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a new "blank" Y axis with no labels.

```
cartesianChart1.Series = new SeriesCollection { };
int counter = 0;

foreach (string number in daten)
{
  cartesianChart1.Series.Add(new RowSeries { Title = titel[counter], Values = new ChartValues<int> { Convert.ToInt16(number) }, DataLabels = true });
  counter++;
}

// Add blank Y axis to hide the default axis.
cartesianChart1.AxisY.Add(new Axis
{
  Labels = new string[0]
});
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Oddly enough, this has changed nothing in my project. Guess I'll just have to live with it.